# how to initialize a char pointer array for an array of strings c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

SO I have to fill an array of words so i can access them later. Ex: nouns = {"boy", "girl", "house"} etc. The trouble is that I have to use a char point array. I have tried this, but it is throwing an error saying error too many initializer values. Here is the code

```
class Sentence
{
    private:
    char* article[sz];
    char* verb[sz];
    char* preposition[sz];
    char* noun[sz];
```

and later I call the constructor like this, but it isn't filling them.

```
Sentence::Sentence()
{
    article[10]  = { "the", "a", "one", "some", "any" };
    verb[] = { "drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped" };
    preposition[] = { "to", "from", "over", "under", "on" };
    noun[] = { "boy ", "girl", "dog", "town", "car" };
}
```

Comment: where is sz defined?

Comment: @Perrin Hawver When and where is sz set?

Comment: also, you're trying to static-initialize an index in your array. that doesn't make sense. get rid of the 10 and the square brackets.

Comment: the sz is set at the top of the program, although I hard coded it to 5 and it is throwing the same error.

Comment: @PerrinHawver If you are going to ask such questions here, you should provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the exact error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I have to fill an array of words so i can access them later.

If that is the core requirement, you will be better off using `std::vector<std::string>` instead of arrays of `char*`.

```
class Sentence
{
    public:
        Sentence();

    private:
        std::vector<std::string> articles;
        std::vector<std::string> verbs;
        std::vector<std::string> prepositions;
        std::vector<std::string> nouns;
};
```

You can initialize the members by using:

```
Sentence::Sentence() : articles{ "the", "a", "one", "some", "any" },
                       verbs{ "drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped" },
                       prepositions{ "to", "from", "over", "under", "on" },
                       nouns{ "boy ", "girl", "dog", "town", "car" }
{
}
```

You can add items to the collections by simply using `push_back` on the member variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize such fixed sized arrays, you can do this in the constructor's member initializer list. It's not possible to do so in the constructor's body.

Supposed that `sz` was declared as e.g.

```
static const size_t sz = 10;
```

you initialize these with the constructor using this syntax

```
Sentence::Sentence() 
: article{ "the", "a", "one", "some", "any" }
, verb{ "drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped" }
, preposition{ "to", "from", "over", "under", "on" }
, noun { "boy ", "girl", "dog", "town", "car" } {
}
```

Alternatively consider using [`std::array<char,sz>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as mentioned in Vlad's answer, or even [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as mentioned by R. Sahu. Any of these should accept this initializer syntax as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `sz` is some constant then you could write

```
#include <array>

//...

const size_t sz = 5;

class Sentence
{
    private:
    std::array<const char *, sz> article;
    std::array<const char *, sz> verb;
    std::array<const char *, sz> preposition;
    std::array<const char *, sz> noun;

//...

Sentence::Sentence()
{
    article  = { "the", "a", "one", "some", "any" };
    verb = { "drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped" };
    preposition = { "to", "from", "over", "under", "on" };
    noun = { "boy ", "girl", "dog", "town", "car" };
}
```

Otherwise you could use `std::vector<const char *>` instead of the arrays.

```
#include <vector>

//...


class Sentence
{
    private:
    std::vector<const char *> article;
    std::vector<const char *> verb;
    std::vector<const char *> preposition;
    std::vector<const char *> noun;

//...

Sentence::Sentence()
{
    article  = { "the", "a", "one", "some", "any" };
    verb = { "drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped" };
    preposition = { "to", "from", "over", "under", "on" };
    noun = { "boy ", "girl", "dog", "town", "car" };
}
```